# Creating Dates in Java

Tags: java, date

I am wondering whats the proper way of creating Dates in Java? It appears the simnplest way

```
new Date(year, month, day, hours, mins)
```

Is depreciated. So how should I create Dates. I understand the recommended way is to use long but whats an easy way to get the long value of a human readable date like "2012-03-21 2:00PM" (or something similar)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class. Or [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), as I'm sure someone else will suggest.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(year, month, day, hours, mins);
long time = c.getTimeInMillis();
```

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill The OP is interested in the UTC value, not the `Date`, per se.

Comment: +1 for recommending Joda Time - Java's Date implementation is easily the worst out of any programming languages I've come across - it's cumbersome and unintuitive. Joda Time makes it much easier.

Answer (score 6):

Since Java 8 you can use the [`Calendar.Builder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.Builder.html) class:

```
Date date = new Calendar.Builder()
    .setDate(2012, 2, 21)
    .setTimeOfDay(14, 0, 0)
    .build().getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
try { 
   String str_date="2012-03-21 2:00PM";
   DateFormat formatter ; 
   Date date ; 
   formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd ha");
   date = (Date)formatter.parse(str_date);  
   Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
   cal.setTime(date);
   System.out.println("Date to long " + cal.getTimeInMillis());
} catch (ParseException e)  {
  System.out.println("Exception :"+e);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to build an appropriate [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) -- which you can use by itself in many cases -- and just call `getDate()` on it if you really need a `Date` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [GregorianCalendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) for dates